# How to merge jacoco reports of two different version - 0.7.9 and 0.8.7

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have execs report of two different jacoco plugins from two different projects -  0.7.9 and 0.8.7 version of jacoco. I want to merge and show a single report. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java -jar jacococli.jar report project1/jacoco.exec project2/jacoco.exec --classfiles project1/classes --classfiles project2/classes --sourcefiles project1/src --sourcefiles project2/src --html report`

Using this command we can do that and it will support from version 0.7.5 to the latest. 0.7.4 and lower are incompatible.